# How to make an OnClick event to add a border to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am attempting to make a 2D version of Minecraft with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML:5. I ran into a problem when constructing the hot bar. I want to apply a border to the button when it is clicked but it comes up with this exception.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at /:11:143
```

Here is the index.HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>2D Minecraft</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <button class="hotbar1" id="hotbar1" onclick="document.getElementById("hotbar1").style.border: 7.5px solid Gray;"/>
    <button class="hotbar2" id="hotbar2"/>
    <button class="hotbar3" id="hotbar3"/>
    <button class="hotbar4" id="hotbar4"/>
    <button class="hotbar5" id="hotbar5"/>
    <button class="hotbar6" id="hotbar6"/>
    <button class="hotbar7" id="hotbar7"/>
    <button class="hotbar8" id="hotbar8"/>
    <button class="hotbar9" id="hotbar9"/>
    <style>
      body{
  background: #191919;
}
.hotbar1{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 17%;
}
.hotbar2{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 24.5%;
}
.hotbar3{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 32%;
}
.hotbar4{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 39.5%;
}
.hotbar5{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 47%;
}
.hotbar6{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 54.5%;
}
.hotbar7{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 62%;
}
.hotbar8{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 69.5%;
}
.hotbar9{
  background: White;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 77%;
}
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is malformed both in the incorrect use of quotes inside of a quoted string and in the way you specify the style change:

```
 onclick="document.getElementById("hotbar1").style.border: 7.5px solid Gray;"
```

it should be

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('hotbar1').style.border='7.5px solid Gray'";
```

Comment: @NathanTolley - please mark this as the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Will do but I can only in 5 min

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! Not to be a stickler, but you can actually accept the answer, which marks it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, I have updated `onclick` of your button, just compare and you will get to know what changed here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>2D Minecraft</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>
    body {
      background: #191919;
    }
    
    .hotbar1 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 17%;
    }
    
    .hotbar2 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 24.5%;
    }
    
    .hotbar3 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 32%;
    }
    
    .hotbar4 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 39.5%;
    }
    
    .hotbar5 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 47%;
    }
    
    .hotbar6 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 54.5%;
    }
    
    .hotbar7 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 62%;
    }
    
    .hotbar8 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 69.5%;
    }
    
    .hotbar9 {
      background: White;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 77%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <button class="hotbar1" id="hotbar1" onclick="document.getElementById('hotbar1').style.border = '7.5px solid red'" />
  <button class="hotbar2" id="hotbar2" />
  <button class="hotbar3" id="hotbar3" />
  <button class="hotbar4" id="hotbar4" />
  <button class="hotbar5" id="hotbar5" />
  <button class="hotbar6" id="hotbar6" />
  <button class="hotbar7" id="hotbar7" />
  <button class="hotbar8" id="hotbar8" />
  <button class="hotbar9" id="hotbar9" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`onclick="document.getElementById("hotbar1").style.border: 7.5px solid Gray;"`

should be:

`onclick="document.getElementById("hotbar1").style = 'border: 7.5px solid Gray'"`